# How do i make self.request.user.account refer to the new inherited Account?

Tags: python, django

I am using a ready module "account" and I want to supplement it with the help of inheritance with another attribute "photo". In models.py I create class Account, that inherits from Account from "account" module.

extended_account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import Account

class Account(Account):
    photo = models.URLField(blank=True, default="default")
```

But in views.py I have no idea how to chains my own Account model with PhotoView. self.request.user.account still refers to the Account from "account" model and has no "photo" attribute.
How do i make self.request.user.account refer to the new Account in extended_account/models.py?

extended_account/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from account.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from extended_account.forms import PhotoForm

class PhotoView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "account/new_photo.html"
    form_class = PhotoForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(PhotoView, self).get_initial()
        initial["photo"] = self.request.user.account.photo
        return initial

    def update_account(self, form):
        fields = {}
        if "photo" in form.cleaned_data:
            fields["photo"] = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
        if fields:
            account = self.request.user.account
            for k, v in fields.items():
                setattr(account, k, v)
            account.save()
```

extended_account/forms.py

```
class PhotoForm(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.URLField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd rename the new account model, so you can have a clear difference between the two.

Then, you can use a ForeignKey instead of inheriting the class. It'd look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import Account

class ExtendedAccount(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="extended_data")
    photo = models.URLField(blank=True, default="default")
    # If you want to add more fields to the account model, do it here
```

Once you have this class, you can create a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) for this class:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ExtendedAccount

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = ExtendedAccount
       fields = ['photo']
```

Now, if you want to access the photo of the model, just do it as a normal ForeignKey:

```
a = Account() # Complete the required fields
a.extended_data.photo
```